# $\frac{1+2iz-e^{2iz}}{z^2}$ is entire

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> $\frac{1+2iz-e^{2iz}}{z^2}$ is entire

Proof. $e^{2iz} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2iz)^n}{n!}$ so $1+2iz-e^{2iz} = 2z^2+\frac{1}{3!}(2iz)^3\cdots$. Hence $\frac{1}{z^2}(1+2iz-e^{2iz}) = 2+\frac{1}{3!}(2i)^3z+\cdots$. Hence, $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1+2iz-e^{2iz}}{z^2} = 2$. Hence $0$ is a removable singularity. Hence, the given function is entire. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, the domain of an entire function must be $\Bbb C$. So, your function cannot possibly be entire, since it is undefined at $0$.

But you argument shows that it can be extended to an entire function.

Comment: Yes it's undefined but the entire above I meant the extended one.